# Remap control key in iTerm2 to caps lock key

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, vim, iterm2

I want to remap the control key to use the caps lock key in iTerm2.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want ctrl to work like caps lock or caps lock to work like ctrl?

Comment: When I press the 'caps lock' key, I want it to behave as if I pressed the 'control' key.

Comment: Is there any reason not to do this system-wide through the `System Preferences => Keyboard => Keyboard (Tab) => Modifier Keys...` screen?

Comment: I would much prefer to restrict it to iTerm for key bindings involving Ctrl. I'm not interested in changing the mapping beyond shell key bindings.

Answer (score 1):

There's a software called Seil. https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en to do just that.

Works on mac. I have been using it for a while and it's great.

I just wonder why I can't map Caps from iTerm direct too.

Seil works not just for iTerm.

Comment: for me it does not work just for iterm. but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531572/mapping-caps-lock-in-vim-onlyfdfSDFdf) does

Comment: Man that's complicated :( Even though I already have Karabiner installed.

Answer (score 0):

This site has a guide: http://azaleasays.com/2013/07/05/setting-up-mac-os-x-and-iterm2-for-emacs/

Iterm2 lets you map left capslock to control.

Comment: The link suggests globally remapping Caps Lock to Ctrl, and not just in iterm